# Matlab matrice index of min (x,y) pair values

Tags: matlab, indexing, minimum

I got a 5 * 5 MATRICE.
I want to find the minimum of (i,j) which corresponds to minimum distance from a fixed point of my grid.

I used: 
`MATRICE(find(MATRICE(1,:))== min(MATRICE(1,:)),:)`
and:

```
[minVal, minInd] = min(MATRICE(:,1));
MATRICE(minInd,1);
[~,MATRICE_2] = min(MATRICE(:,:));
```

`disp(MATRICE_2)` gets me the correct `row(i)` of the MATRICE but `column(j)` isn't displayed at all.

Comment: I'm not clear what you are trying to do. Can you give some clearer examples of your inputs and expected output?

Comment: I have a grid with fixed points on axis points configured by a meshgrid 'x,y = meshgrid(1:1:5)'. Into the grid random users are generated and uniformly distributed. Fixed point's distance and random user's distances are measured with the euclidean formula. Also distances between fixed points and random users are measured too and results are forming the MATRICE. So this MATRICE is consisted from 5 * 5 coordinate distance vectors. Now in order to associate each random user to its closest fixed point i want to find min x,y of the MATRICE in every simulation iteration

Comment: ok thanks for the update, it sounds like angainor's answer is what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand correctly, but if you want to find the `(row,col)` indices of the smallest entry in your array, you can use this

```
[i,j] = ind2sub(size(MATRICE), find(MATRICE==min(MATRICE(:))))
```

where `A` is your matrix. This works by changing your matrix to a vector of 25 elements, looking for the position of the smallest value, and converting that position to a `(row,col)` pair by using `ind2sub`.

What you wrote finds minimum entry in every column of your matrix. So, every `i` entry in `MATRICE_2` shows the row index of minimum value in the column `i`. In other words, column and row indices are

```
cols = 1:numel(MATRICE_2);
rows = MATRICE_2;
```

Answer (score 0):

OK i figure it out:

```
[MinValue, MinIndex] = min(MATRICE(:));
MinSub =ind2sub(size(MATRICE), MinIndex);
```

MinValue is the minimum value of the MATRICE and MinIndex the index of it plus is pointing the fixed point directly.